# balanced parentheses - when stack is mandatory?

Tags: c, algorithm

If I want to check a string for valid parentheses usage, I can use this simple code:

```
int counter = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < length_of_string; i++){
    if(string[i] == '(' )
       counter++;
    else if(string[i] == ')' )    // string is a char array
       counter--;
    if(counter < 0)
       return -1; // error because the ')' should come AFTER '('
}
if(counter == 0)
     return 0; // the string is OK
else
     return -1; // unbalanced
```

My question is this - I think this code is doing the job well but I've seen some implementations using a stack. Why is that? Is using stack gives me the ability to handle more elaborated cases?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Are you asking why some people solve this problem with a stack and some don't?

Comment: also, what do you exactly mean by _stack_?

Comment: If you *only want to know* whether there are unbalanced parentheses you don't need a stack. If you want to parse an expression you need it and not only for parentheses.

Comment: Just to clarify: I think this solution is good. I know some people use a solution that includes a stack (in C++, JAVA and such) but I don't know why - are they solving the same problem or a more sophisticated one?

Comment: @CIsForCookies I can't tell you without actually seeing their solutions. While we are at it, could you tell me what's wrong with my dog? He looks a bit pale.

Comment: @CIsForCookies You got it right. They are solving a more sophisticated problem, the problem of parsing an expression.

Comment: For this specific case it doesn't seem like a stack is needed.  But if the structure is more complex, then you need to save context, which a stack solves.  For instance, if you have both parentheses `()` and square brackets `[]`, and you want to make sure they are properly nested, then simply counting them will no longer suffice.

Comment: @TomKarzes can't that be achieved by using 2 counters? let's say my string is 100 chars, and there are both () and [], so I have a counter that increments by 1 for the (), and counter that increments by 1000 for []. Wouldn't that work?

Comment: @TomKarzes Good observation.

Comment: No, that won't check proper nesting.  Consider `([)]`.  That should give an error.  But your simple counter solution wouldn't distinguish it from `([])`

Comment: You can think of your counter as a kind of degenerate stack -- the only thing you can push on it are `(`s, so you just need to know how deep the stack is.  So `++` is your push operation, `--` is your pop operation, and `<0` is your 'empty?' operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If for just balancing parentheses, using a stack has these advantages:

- You can point the user to the offset of the unclosed parenthesis;
- You can balance different types of grouping operators such as `[]`, `{}` and `()` and verify that they are correctly nested.

Note that you may need to parse your string more carefully if you want to support string, character, regular expression literals and possibly comments.

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to check for mismatched parentheses you don't need to create a stack and your code is just fine. If you want to parse an expression (*mathematical for example*) you certainly need a stack of characters to push operators and parentheses. Read [this for more information](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parsing/RPN_calculator_algorithm).

Answer (score 2):

Using a `stack` is very easy to understand and also efficient. This is since you could just `Push` to the stack when you see an opening tag (`(`) and `Pop` when you see a closing one (`)`). This works very similarly to your code using a counter.

To check if a string with parentheses is legal you just need to `return is_stack_empty(my_stack);` (or any variant of this) and you have your result.

Note: it is true, like people stated, that using a `stack` here might not be the way to go, since a counter does the job perfectly. But as stated, a `stack` works very well with mathematical expressions like an expression that can have several types of tags ( `() , [] , {}`).

Comment: What is `myStack.Empty()`? It's certainly not [tag:c]. But the most impotant thing is that you need to read the question, this does not answer the question.

Comment: I disagree. my answer solves the question asked and explains why people choose to use a stack for this. and as I stated, I know that Empty() isn't c, you could use any other function that follows this logic and it's very easy.

Comment: BTW: I think the OP knows how to use a stack.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code in Java using **Stack**, it can help you to balance multiple brackets

```
public boolean isValid(String s) {
    HashMap<Character, Character> closeBracketMap = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
    closeBracketMap.put(')', '(');
    closeBracketMap.put(']', '[');
    closeBracketMap.put('}', '{');
    HashSet<Character> openBracketSet = new HashSet<Character>(
        closeBracketMap.values());
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();

    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        char cur = chars[i];
        if (openBracketSet.contains(cur)) {
            stack.push(cur);
        } else { // close brackets
            if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }
            if (closeBracketMap.get(cur) != stack.peek()) {
                return false;
            }
            stack.pop();
        }
    }

    return stack.isEmpty();
}
```

And here is the code without using **Stack**:

```
public class Groups{
  public static boolean groupCheck(String s) {
    int len;
    do {
      len = s.length();
      s = s.replace("()", "");
      s = s.replace("{}", "");
      s = s.replace("[]", "");
    } while (len != s.length());
    return s.length() == 0;
  }
}
```

**That means we will remove one by one bracket.**

For example: String s = "" (len = 10; s.length() = 10) it will remove "[]", "[]", "()".

Then s = "({})" (s.length() = 4) it will continue to remove "{}".

Then s = "()" (s.length() = 2), it will continue to remove "()".

Then s = "" (s.length() = 0). It will break the loop because ( (len == 10) != (s.length() == 0) ).

Then we will be able to check it is true. :)